# Permission denied while trying to copy some data from computer on to Samsung Galaxy J5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung

I updated the firmware couple of days ago. After that I've been trying in vain to copy some data from my linux (Debian box) to Samsung Galaxy J5, SM-J500F

This is the command I have been using -

```
─[$] sudo cp some-content /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A005%2C019%5D/Card/Android/media/Music_CD
```

Music CD was a directory made by me some months ago.

I get the following response -

```
cp: failed to access '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A005%2C019%5D/Card/Android/media/Music_CD': Permission denied
```

Any idea why permission denied error is being given even though I'm sudo.

Android version is 6.0.1 . Please let me know if more details are needed as developer options are turned on.

Comment: Do you have root access on your phone ? Did you root it?

Comment: I haven't rooted it but sometime before I was able to copy effortlessely, without the need of root access.

Comment: It was working on lower versions of Android not Marshmallow

Comment: I *think* it was working on marshmallow too, but not the most recent update.